# スプレッドシートからBigQueryに接続してデータを取得する時にトリガーだと失敗する

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

BigQueryで集計したデータをGASで取得してスプレッドシートに出力する処理を書きました。

取得するためのクエリは以下です。

```
select * from
(SELECT appid, count(userno) as cnt FROM [hogehoge.dau_20151201] 
group by appid having count(userno) > 1000)
order by cat desc
```

GASの実装は、トレタの増井さんがブログで紹介していたものをベースにしています。
http://toreta.blog.jp/archives/20649904.html

スプレッドシートで"BigQuery->全シート内容を更新"とすると問題なく実行できます。

しかしこれをトリガーで１日１回自動実行させようとしたところ、
以下のようなエラーが出て処理が失敗してしまいます。

> runAllQueries Not found: Table hugahuga:hogehoge.dau_20151207

トリガーで実行する場合に何か権限が違うといったようなことがあるものでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

メニューから選択した場合と、トリガーで呼び出す場合でユーザが異なるケースはありえます。
始めてメニューからGASを呼び出した際に表示された認証画面で選択したユーザと、
トリガーを設定した際にに表示された認証画面で選択したユーザが異なる可能性が高いです。

一度トリガーを削除し、再度トリガーを作成、認証画面が表示されるはずなので権限を持っているユーザを選択してみてください。

Comment: トリガーを作り直してみましたが状況が変わりませんでした。。。

Comment: 権限の問題と、実行時間の問題と２つあったようで認証し直したとでトリガーの実行時間も見直したところうまくいきました。